# Where is hybrid model in MobileFirst 8

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-studio

I am starting to learn MobileFirst development and have a question regarding Hybrid development model.

I was looking at version 7.1 which supports Hybrid development that allows you to create applications that work on all supported devices.

But then I found out that there is a latest version of MobileFirst Foundation available called 8.0 but strangely Hybrid model is not there. Has it been replaced by something else?

By the way shall I go with version 7.1 or 8?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no longer a concept of "hybrid application" in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0 (in the way that you are accustomed to in 7.1 and prior versions).  Instead, you would create a Cordova application using your preferred Cordova development tools, and add the MobileFirst SDK to it.  See the tutorial at https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/release-notes/whats-new/ (in the "What's new in building apps" section) for additional details.

Comment: Isn't this like going a step backward? If you take a look at this link, IBM lists several advantages of Hybrid over Cordova so I don't know why would they remove Hybrid model from newer versions.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_cordova_vs_hybrid.html

Comment: Well, thats not entirely true - the comparison in the link is between a Cordova app and MobileFirst 7.1 hybrid app. When you add the MobileFirst cordova plugin to a regular Cordova app, several of the capabilities of a hybrid app are available to the cordova app as well. For example, certification pinning, encrypting web resources and many others.

Comment: Absolutely not true.  The Hybrid model in 7.x was a proprietary, non-standard approach for cross-platform development. With 8.0, you're using the same Cordova that everyone else is. The MFF 8.0 SDK is delivered as a Cordova plugin, you use standard Cordova CLI, and the folder structure of the project is standard Cordova as well.  100% improvement, IMO.